# babel/polyfill is deprecated warning in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, babel-polyfill

I have a `React` app that I created using `npx create-react-app my-app`. I've been regularly updating both `React` and other `npm` packages.

A while ago, I started getting the following warning:

> @babel/polyfill is deprecated. Please, use required parts of core-js
>   and regenerator-runtime/runtime separately

The following is what's in my `package.json` file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0"
  }
```

I found a few articles online about how to handle this but none of them look like the official solution. What's the right way to handle this?

So far, this has been a warning and not an error so I just postponed dealing with it. Today, I upgraded the `moment` package and that started giving me an error and I figured dealing with this issue first is a good starting point.

I'd appreciate some pointers in making this warning go away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

babel-polyfill is being replaced by core-js. You can remove babel-polyfill and install core-js instead. After you have installed core-js update the babel presets in your .babelrc or babel.config.js file with the following:

```
"presets":[
  ['@babel/preset-env',
  {
    useBuiltIns: 'usage',
    corejs: 3,
  }],
]
```

If you are importing babel-polyfill in your App you can remove that too. Also you can add a targets property in your presets

```
[
  '@babel/preset-env',
  {
    targets: {
      browsers: ['> 0.25%, not dead'],
    },
    useBuiltIns: 'usage',
    corejs: 3,
  },
]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not following your instructions fully. I replaced `"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"` with `"core-js": "3.6.5"` under the `devDependencies` section in the `package.json` file but when I run `npm start` to compile my React app, I'm still getting the same error as I was getting before. I do NOT see a `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` file in my app's directory. I do, however, see a ton of references to `babel` in the `package-lock.json` file. Before I installed `core-js`, I deleted the `npm_modules` folder along with `package-lock.json` file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Basically, I updated my `package.json` file to use `core-js` instead of `babel-pollyfill`, removed `npm_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file. Then ran `npm i` to install all the packages fresh. Anyway, as I mentioned before, I'm still getting the same error when I start the compilation process.

Comment: I apologize you said you were using Create React App @Sam

Comment: Also, my `react-scripts` package is up-to-date i.e. `"react-scripts": "^3.4.1"`. I thought there may be references in there to `babel`.

Comment: Yes, I created my React app using Create React App. How does that affect this?

Comment: Unfortunately its not easy to customize the babel config using CRA without ejecting. Found a way. Let me know if this points you in the right direction. https://devinschulz.com/modify-create-react-apps-babel-configuration-without-ejecting/ @sam

Comment: Once you can get a hold of customizing the babel config file update it with with the above answer.

Comment: I feel this whole process goes against the idea of using `create-react-app`? This is what I hate about `JavaScript` development. I'm constantly distracted from developing the app that I'm supposed to work on to deal with all these lower level concerns -- sorry just venting but I honestly feel that way.

Comment: Just looking at `create-react-app` repo and looks like that's been updated and in `package.json` file, I see that they removed references to `babel`.

Comment: No I definitely feel your pain @Sam. Actually I myself have moved on to Golang myself because of this very same issue in JS dev. But with CRA you have essentially "locked" yourself into their defaults.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your help. I'll mark it as answer.